# AVAudioPlayer crashes intermittently

Tags: ios, audio, media, avaudioplayer

I have an application that makes heavy use of audio. I use AVAudioPlayers to simplify the task.

I've noticed crashes from time to time when using the players, usually when I call [player play]. The stack trace looks something like this:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS
#0  0x32d531e6 in memmove$VARIANT$CortexA8 ()
#1  0x351056dc in Cached_DataSource::ReadFromHeaderCache ()
#2  0x351052a4 in Cached_DataSource::ReadBytes ()
#3  0x350ba47c in AudioFileObject::ReadBytes ()
#4  0x35104562 in AudioFileObject::ReadPacketDataVBR ()
#5  0x35102c70 in AudioFileObject::ReadPacketData ()
#6  0x351020b2 in AudioFileReadPacketData ()
#7  0x36bad1b8 in AudioPlayerAQOutputCallbackCore ()
#8  0x36bad7a4 in prepareToPlayQueue ()
#9  0x36bad954 in playQueue ()
#10 0x36bac27e in -[AVAudioPlayer play] ()
```

I have breakpoints set up in every dealloc call, so I know that I'm not inadvertently dealloc-ing a player or delegate or similar.

The players are sometimes stopped before they play their full sound, so I always make a [player setCurrentTime:0] call before playing. I'm not sure if this could cause some negative side effects.

Clearly the audio queue is trying to access invalid memory, but from the looks of things that memory lives way down in the file cache code, so I can't see how anything I'm doing would affect it. All of the files I'm playing are included as resources in the main bundle.

I created a repro that reliably reproduces this in the 4.1 simulator and on my 5.0.1 device. It can take a little while and hundreds of calls to setCurrentTime, play, and stop before it crashes.

I need to get to the bottom of this. I can start porting all of my code to use audio queues or something else if required, but I want to make sure that there isn't something I'm missing or that I could do differently to make this more stable.

Comment: If you could provide a simple reproducible example of this behaviour it would avoid the community doing any heavy lifting